Postgresql ignores ORDER BY when using a variable, gives correct results when the variable value is hard coded
Following query returns rows that are ordered by id, even though sortType variable value is 'e.name' (confirmed in console)
export async function fetchAnimalList(sortType) {
  noStore();

  try {
    const areas = await sql<Animals>`
    SELECT e.id, e.name, e.slug, e.sliderarray, e.location, e.classification1, a.name AS locationname
    FROM animals e
    JOIN areas a ON (e.location = a.displayorder)
    ORDER BY ${sortType}
  `;
    return areas.rows;
  } 
}


Function that passes the variable looks like this:
const animalList = await fetchAnimalList('e.name');
Replacing  ${sortType} with manually written e.name returns rows that are ordered by e.name as expected.
What could possibly be the problem?

Please check the SQL statement that is generated, see the log file

Have a look into the tag function

What programming language and database library are you using? If ${sortType} only does string interpolation, it shouldn't make any difference. If it's using prepared statements and bind parameters, you're sorting by a constant text, 'e.name'; you cannot use bind parameters to generate SQL dynamically, because it's a tool specifically designed to prevent that.

I don't use any database libraries. I'm using React(next.js) with typescript. Hosting my database on Vercel and having limited experience with postgresql, I couldn't figure how to start logging and read the logs of Vercel. I tried to console.log the query (everything that is inside ``ticks) and my terminal returned it with only e.name, no quotes attached.

According to official tutorial, you're probably using Vercel Postgres SDK. As stated:
"The Vercel Postgres SDK provides protection against SQL injections". I've no idea how it works.

At a guess the library replaces the interpolation with a variable, so you end up with ORDER BY @p1 where the value of @p1 is e.name. This does not work as it's a constant value.

You are trying to use a parameter in place of an identifier (a column name), which doesn't work. Instead, your variable is substituted as a string constant, so the actual statement becomes:
SELECT ... ORDER BY 'e.name'

Sorting by a constant has no effect.
